# Finding points within a multi-variable calculus function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the following function.

$f (x, y)  =  [(y + 6) ln x] − xe^2y − x(y − 5)5$

(a) Find  $f_x(1, 0)$ .

(b) Find  $f_y(1, 0)$ .

I know that I should separate them into two different equations but I do not know how to separate it. I believe that after that I should plug in the numbers to point into the equations to get the final answer but I do not know how to make them into 2 equation. I could really use them help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$fx(x,y)=(0+6)⋅1(1)−e^{2(0)}−(y−5)^5 =3130$

and

$fy(x,y) = ln(1)−2(1)e^{2(0)}−5(1)(0−5)^4 = -3127$

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to separate into different equations, you simply need to take the partial derivatives of $f$ and evaluate them at the same point. Something I found useful when first calculating partial derivatives is to set $g(x)=f(x,c)$ where $c$ is a constant. Then just take the normal derivative of $g$. Do likewise with $y$. You do not need to do this, but I felt it was harder to make mistakes when the other variable is represented by a symbol normally used for constants.

Comment: But if I evaluate them the same way, how do i know which is $f_x$ and which is $f_y$?

Comment: You evaluate them at the same point, however, $f_y$ does not necessarily equal $f_x$. Do you know about partial derivatives?

Comment: $f_x$ is the derivative of $f$ taken with respect to $x$. So if $f(x, y) = x^2 y$, then $f_x(x, y) = 2xy$ and $f_y(x, y) = x^2$. Then if you evaluate both of them at $(1, 0)$ then you would get $f_x(1, 0) = 2 \times 1 \times 0 = 0$ and $f_y(1, 0) = 1^2 = 1$. You evaluate the two of them in the same way, but they are different functions so they take different values.

Comment: I think i get it! I will give it a shoot!

Comment: Yeah, I still don't understand how to do this with the information you have given @ConMan

Comment: I have a question similar to this

Comment: @Kimmy.J Feel free to ask it, I'm sure I or someone else will have a shot at answering it.

Comment: Hey @Kimmy.J! I think I have the answer for it!

Comment: @GuachoPerez If you can check over it that would be great. You too ConMan